# Is this old music video really from North Korea as opposed to South Korea?

Tags: north-korean, history-of-korean

When looking at this music video, apparently decades old, claimed to be from North Korea, I'm somewhat puzzled.

Something about the office, the computers, the subway and how people dress and act makes me feel as if this couldn't really be North Korea, but I could simply be ignorant, in spite of really trying for a long time to get a proper grasp of North Korea. (Which means I have to ignore massive amounts of unflattering propaganda.)

Is this music video perhaps "highly stylized" in the same way that some "gangster rapper" from the USA never actually shows reality in their music videos?

I guess what makes me so puzzled is how authentic it looks.

I frankly thought that North Korea, or at least the main city, got a subway as late as only a few years ago. I remember watching a video where the leader took a first test-trip on it, but maybe that was just their *new* subway and it already existed for a long time before that?

Would be nice to get this straightened out.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFzMZ32h9Yk

Comment: Although the Pyongyang Metro is relatively small, it is coming up to _half a century_ old now: operations started all the way back in 1973.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was definitely filmed in Pyongyang. Here's why ---

> (1) In the credits it says it was filmed in Pyongyang

> (2) They're all wearing the Kim Il Sung badge

> (3) At around 20 seconds there's a backdrop of the 조선컴퓨터센터 in Pyongyang

> (4) There are chandeliers on the subway ceiling, as they do in Pyongyang

> (5) They don't hug or kiss but shake hands at the end

Comment: Would also upvote if the site would let me.